# Function receiving char * as if it's empty

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

I've been pulling my hairs out on this one, so this is how I call the function:

```
char* to_send;

to_send = "GOO";

write_client_msg(new_fd, to_send);
```

And this is the function:

```
void write_client_msg(int new_fd, char * msg)
{
    printf("\nwrite_client_msg\n");
    printf("Message is: ", msg);
    int n = write(new_fd, msg, strlen(msg));
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("Erreur lors de la transmission de message");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

And the result to that is the following:

```
write_client_msg
Message is:
```

It's just empty... I don't understand and I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("Message is: ", msg);
```

You forgot format specifier above. You need to use `%s` format specifier for printing C style strings, e.g., see below:

```
printf("Message is: %s ", msg);
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you. yes now it shows the correct message, which means my problem is elsewhere.